# Left Join in Subsonic3

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I'm new in subsonic3, and I'm getting some errors when I try to use LeftJoin

```
    var q =

    from c in categories

    join p in products on c equals p.Category into ps

    from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()

    select new { Category = c, ProductName = p == null ? "(No products)" : p.ProductName };
```

The error is 
"System.Collections.Generic.Enumerable '...' cannot be used for parameter of type System.Linq.IQueryable

Does anyone had this error before? Did you fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Could you try pulling the latest version from http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0 and report back on whether you still run into this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which one is the IQueryable property but you probably know, just add the .AsEnumerable() method.

```
categories.AsEnumerable() or products.AsEnumerable()
```

I cant remember if you had to add the toList() method also but you can try it out.

```
categories.AsEnumerable().toList() or products.AsEnumerable().toList()
```